# How to resolve dependency vulnerabilities in my GitHub repository

Tags: javascript, vue.js, github, vuex, eslint

I am attempting to develop and maintain repository for a CLI-based Vue.js project in GitHub. I just received a notification regarding a security vulnerability with one of my dependencies. The message says that I need to upgrade `eslint-utils` to a new version in either the dependencies or the devDependencies list. I am looking at the package.json file for my project, and am not seeing `eslint-utils` in either list, only `eslint` and `eslint-plugin-vue` in the devDependencies list. Any recommendations on how to resolve this? Should I add `eslint-utils` as a dependency? I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: `eslint-utils` is a dependency of one of your dependencies in `package.json`. It can be found in `package-lock.json`. Just update (`npm update`) all your current packages to latest version, they should have updated their dependency version, if not wait a few days. Don't explicitly add `eslint-utils` to your `package.json`. Anyway it will be a dev-dependency so no need to worry about security of your production build

Comment: This worked. Thank you!